# How to iterate over items in QScriptValue which isArray()?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtscript

So I have this code:

```
QScriptValue result(someFunction());
if(result.isArray()) {
{
    // Print items in array
}
```

How can I do it? I tried to convert it to `QList<QScriptValue>` but that doesn't work. I considered doing this:

```
    const int length = (int)result.property("length").toNumber();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        const QSCriptValue entry(result.property(QString::number(i)))));
        // do something with entry
    }
```

It works but seems kinda ugly.

Comment: Keep in mind that module got deprecated.

Comment: In case you can switch to the new `QJSEngine`, the `QJSValue` class has a property function overload that accepts an array index: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsvalue.html#property-1

Answer (score 0):

Based on `QScriptValue` help, probably something like:

```
for(v: result.toVariant().as<QVariantList>()) {
    // here v is a QVariant-item
}
```

Needs testing to see if it actually.